Check for pending commits in React in a Suspense-compatible way?
I wrote a simple animation hook that needs to wait for React to commit renders (for concurrent mode) before painting updates. I have something like this:
function useAnimation() {
  const hasCommittedRef = useRef(false);
  hasCommittedRef.current = false;

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    hasCommittedRef.current = true;
  });

  const handleUpdate = () => {
    if (!hasCommittedRef.current) {
      // don't paint yet
    }
    // paint
  };
}

Without Suspense, this works perfectly. With Suspense, if the component that calls this hook renders, suspends, then unsuspends: hasCommittedRef.current would always stay false.
E.g. here's a Codesandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/youthful-fast-7vzmkz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A4%2C1
import React from "react";

const infiniteThenable = { then() {} };

function Inner() {
  console.log("Inner");

  const [isSuspended, setIsSuspended] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsSuspended(false);
    }, 500);
  }, []);

  if (isSuspended) {
    throw infiniteThenable;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  console.log("App");

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("App effect");
  });

  return (
    <React.Suspense>
      <Inner />
    </React.Suspense>
  );
}

This logs:
App
Inner
App effect
Inner

Since the useLayoutEffect doesn't run again, I can't use this method to check if there's a pending commit. Is there a way to check for pending commits that works with Suspense?
